# Redirect на страницу, на которую пользователь хотел перейти до авторизации asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, auth

Работаю над проектом, который состоит из asp.net mvc (в частности страница авторизации) и части на angularjs (полностью SPA).

В данный момент, при попытке перейти по любой ссылке приводит к перенаправлению на страницу авторизации, но после авторизации (когда нажали на кнопку log in) пользователь попадает на дефолтную страницу, которая определена в методе действия.

Требуется, что бы перенаправление произошло на ту ссылку, которую пользователь попытался открыть с самого начала. Если не пытался, то отправить на дефолтную.

Как настроить этот процесс перенаправления, если пользователь не авторизован?

Контроллер и метод действия, для подтверждения авторизации уже есть: на view, помимо `input` для логина и пароля есть еще `hidden input`, предназначенный для url, на который хотел перейти пользователь.

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    var password = PasswordHash.Encrypt(model.Password);

    var user = _userManagerService.GetUser(model.Username, password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        FormsAuthHelper.SetAuthenticationCookie(Response, user);

        if (returnUrl.Length > 1)
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Invoice");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы так делаете? Если у вас SPA - то и авторизацию делайте там же.

Comment: Я работаю над очень большим проектом, его не возможно просто так взять и полностью сделать SPA :), поэтому этот вопрос касательно только MVC asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение из заголовка "referer" (при запросе формы) положить в скрытое поле формы, например. Если значение не обнаружено - редирект на дефолтную страницу.

```
public class AutorizedOnly : AuthorizeAttribute
{ 

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (/*is NOT autorized*/) {
            Uri returnTo = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Login", "Accounting", new { returnUrl = returnTo });
        }
    } 
}

public class Accounting : Controller {
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResul Login(Uri returnTo) {
        ViewBag.returnTo = returnTo.ToString();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResul Login(string returnTo, SignInModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            if (/*login success*/) {
                /* Set cookie with session id */
                return Redirect(returnTo);
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47703/discussion-on-answer-by-free-ze-redirect------).